# Running custom gradle task when one module builds

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm confused on where to declare a custom gradle task and how to control when it's run.

I have a project with several modules. In (only) one of them I'd like to execute a script at any point of its build process.

So i have declared the task in the **modules's** build.gradle

```
task generateAssets(type:Exec) {

    commandLine './scripts/generate_assets.sh'
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

    ext.output = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}
```

And nothing happens, what I kind of expected, as I suppose I will have to call this task or something like that, but I don't know how.

How can I do it?

Comment: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html#sec:task_dependencies

Comment: but is it OK to put it in the module's build.gradle instead of on the top-level build.gradle?

Comment: I don't see why not. For what you've shown, it just matters where your shell script exists, and what it does

Comment: That script path will be resolved into any number of locations.  If you are running a the gradle daemon for example it _could_ run relative to the daemon `cwd` or relative to your root project.  You can make a `File` object with: `rootProject.file( './scripts/generate_assets.sh' )` and set paths using: `"${rootProject.rootDir}/scripts/generate_assets.sh"`.  That way I am sure the correct file is used.